# Create JS chrome snippet to auto scroll page up and down in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I need to show content of Jira dashboard on screen and scroll it up and down automaticly inside infinite loop.
I tried to create Chrome Snippet but for/while loops seems not work.

```
function scroll(speed) {
    $('html, #ghx-pool').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, speed, function() {
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, speed);
    });
}
while(true){
    setInterval(scroll(25000), 10);  
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this code?